# I cant figure out whats wrong with this command in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This command I've been trying to perform. I got the code from minersneedcoolshoes.com I used the banner maker, made a bunch of banners, and clicked export to chest. It says that there is unbalanced curly brackets. My eyes have issues focusing on all the brackets, which makes me unable to see the issue. I hope you can help me.

Command (I've split it up to different banners)

```
/setblock 13 65 9 minecraft:chest 0 replace 
{Items:
[{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:0,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:ts,Color:4},{Pattern:rs,Color:4},{Pattern:hhb,Color:15},{Pattern:ms,Color:4},{Pattern:ls,Color:4},{Pattern:drs,Color:4},{Pattern:bo,Color:15}]}}},
{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:1,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:ts,Color:4},{Pattern:bs,Color:4},{Pattern:ms,Color:4},{Pattern:ls,Color:4},{Pattern:bo,Color:15}]}}},
{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:2,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:ls,Color:4},{Pattern:rs,Color:4},{Pattern:ts,Color:4},{Pattern:ms,Color:4},{Pattern:bo,Color:15}]}}},
{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:3,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:bo,Color:15},{Pattern:ls,Color:4},{Pattern:bs,Color:4},{Pattern:bo,Color:15}]}}},
{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:4,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:drs,Color:4},{Pattern:dls,Color:4},{Pattern:hhb,Color:15},{Pattern:ls,Color:4},{Pattern:rs,Color:4}]}}},
{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:8,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:bo,Color:15}]}}},
{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:9,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:bo,Color:15},{Pattern:ls,Color:4},{Pattern:bs,Color:4},{Pattern:bo,Color:15}]}}},
{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:10,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:ls,Color:4},{Pattern:rs,Color:4},{Pattern:ts,Color:4},{Pattern:ms,Color:4},{Pattern:bo,Color:15}]}}},
{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:11,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:ls,Color:4},{Pattern:rs,Color:4},{Pattern:drs,Color:4},{Pattern:bo,Color:15}]}}},
{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:12,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:bo,Color:15},{Pattern:cs,Color:4},{Pattern:ts,Color:4},{Pattern:bs,Color:4},{Pattern:bo,Color:15}]}}},
{id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:13,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:ls,Color:4},{Pattern:rs,Color:4},{Pattern:ts,Color:4},{Pattern:ms,Color:4},{Pattern:bo,Color:15}]}}},}]}
```

I always split my commands like this, so that its easier to read.

Comment: I recommend copying it into Notepad++. It has a feature for detecting corresponding brackets (there's an extra } somewhere).

Answer (score 4):

You've got an extra right curly brace before the very last square bracket:

> {id:minecraft:banner,Count:1,Slot:13,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Base:15,Patterns:[{Pattern:ls,Color:4},{Pattern:rs,Color:4},{Pattern:ts,Color:4},{Pattern:ms,Color:4},{Pattern:bo,Color:15}]}}},**}**]}

Breaking down the last 5 characters:

> } - closes the {id
>
> , - separating this {id} from the next (unnecessary, but should be ignored)
>
> } - error
>
> ] - closes the Items:[] collection
>
> } - closes the replace object